# How can I profile a .Net 6 xUnit test?

Tags: c#, xunit, profiler

I have seen this question asked and answered before, but the solutions no longer work for .Net 6 or rely on 3rd party libraries that are no longer maintained and don't have .Net 6 support.

I have some xUnit tests that are taking too much time to run and I'd like to profile them to see where the time is being spent.

I've tried ANTS and DotTrace but cannot get either to run the project and give me a profile.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

I've tried numerous suggested solutions for adding a `Program.cs` file and letting the tests project also run as a console app, but none work in the latest .Net versions.

Comment: What is the problem in detail? What does not work? Profiling one of my xUnit tests based on .NET 6 using dotTrace works as usual, both within Rider and Visual Studio

Comment: Works fine for me as well. Do you have any error message or similar?

Comment: How do you start the profiler run? I just right-clicked the unit test project in VS and selected "Profile Unit Tests"

Comment: How are you setting up dottrace to run an xUnit project? I couldn't find instructions.

Comment: I do not see any context menu option to profile a test project or test in the Test Explorer or Solution explorer. Using VS 17.6.5